# ERROR Error: [Reanimated] The native part of Reanimated doesn't seem to be initialized

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

ERROR  Error: [Reanimated] The native part of Reanimated doesn't seem to be initialized. This could be caused by

- not rebuilding the app after installing or upgrading Reanimated
- trying to run Reanimated on an unsupported platform
- running in a brownfield app without manually initializing the native library, js engine: hermes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to reanimated failure to build.

Assuming it comes with :

```
    FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\USER\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build.gradle' line: 626

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:assertLatestReactNativeWithNewArchitectureTask'.
>
  [react-native-reanimated] Reanimated 3.3.0 supports the New Architecture only on the latest minor release of React Native. Please upgrade to React Native 0.72.0+ or downgrade to an older version of Reanimated v3.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 32s
```

you can try downgrading reanimated

```
npm i react-native-reanimated@3.0.0
```